# Why is Google not Indexing most of my pages it found?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index, next.js

When I visit search console, it shows 5 indexes pages and 18 pages not index. But no error whatsoever.

Why is google not indexing my pages?

Where can I get more information about why it's not being indexed?

How can I resolve that? The pages which are not indexed are not different from the pages that are indexed. I have no robots.txt which prevents them from being crawled.

https://state-less.cloud/lists has been added yesterday and is indexed, whereas https://state-less.cloud/faq is not indexed despite being older.

[image]